# MySQL View decimal place

Tags: mysql, sql, decimal, rounding

I have a  MySQL view called `Balance` created from 2 tables `order` and `income` with  PHPMyAdmin  and contains some calculated fields ex: `CustomerBalance` the decimal place become automatically 8, I mean the field  Type is `decimal(50,8)`
How can i make it 2 only ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use truncate

```
 SELECT TRUNCATE(1.999,2);
```

return   `1.99`

```
 select TRUNCATE(your_column,2) from your_table;
```

Comment: perfet, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

In the `select` list where you calculate the `CustomerBalance` expression, explicitly truncate or round (depending on your requirements) the result to 2 digits:

```
select ... round(..., 2) as CustomerBalance ...
```